# how to add row as html to BootStrap Plugin DataTable?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Is there a way to add row as html to datatable? I understand that the suggested way of doing it is this:

```
$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
        t.row.add( [
            counter +'.1',
            counter +'.2',
            counter +'.3',
            counter +'.4',
            counter +'.5'
        ] ).draw( false );

        counter++;
    } );
```

But I have a complex JSON input and I want to pre process it in PHP. Is it doable or even possible?

EDIT:

So instead of doing the code above:

```
 t.row.add(resultfromphpserverwithalltherows);
```

UPDATE:

JSON output

```
{"student":[{"id":"2008-161","name":"Joseph Taylor","age":"20","status":"married","address":"USA","subjects":[{"math":"90","science":96,"history":99,"literature":93,"pe":"96"}],"remarks":"passed"}
```

and sometimes:

```
{"student":[{"id":"2008-161","name":"Joseph Taylor","age":"20","status":"married","address":"USA","subjects":[{"math":"90","science":96,"history":99,"literature":93,"pe":"96"}],"remarks":"passed","othersubjects":[{"applied math":"90","general science":96,"world history":99,"literature":93,"pe":"96"}],"remarks":"passed"}
```

So I can't really define the columns because the JSON output is dynamic and that's why I want to preprocess it in PHP first.

Answer (score 1):

No matter how you approach this, there's going to be some significant data-formatting required.

## Best approach for what you're asking: [use DataTables server-side tools](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html).

It requires including some additional components, but will simplify the javascript down to:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
} );
```

...with a little tweaking, you can simplify that further:

```
$(function(){
    var dt = new dataTableAuto();
    dt.load();
});

function dataTableAuto() {
    this.params = {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    };

    this.load = function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( this.params );
    }
}
```

## php ajax server to send raw JSON as a single row

Simply send an ajax request to php which includes the counter, then respond with a json array matching what you want to build.

#### Javascript snippet

```
counter = 0;

$.ajax({
    url: '[your url]',
    type: 'post',
    data: {"counter":counter},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        t.row.add(JSON.parse(response)).draw( false );
        counter++;
    },
});
```

#### php Snippet

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($jsonString);
$counter = $data['counter'];
$totalRows = 10;

for( $i = 0; $i < $totalRows; $i++) {
    $result[] = $counter .".". $i;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json', true, 200);
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

## [DataTables pure AJAX approach](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

#### javascript

```
$(function(){
    t = $('#example');

    $.ajax({
        url: '[your url]',
        type: 'post',
        data: {"classID":12},
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            t.DataTable( JSON.parse(response) );
        },
    });
});
```

#### php

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($jsonString);
$classID = intval($data['classID']);

$cols = array('Name', 'Position', 'Score');
foreach ( $cols as $colName ) {
    $entry = new stdClass();
    $entry->title = $colName;
    $result['columns'][] = $entry;
}

$result = // some query [ex: get rows by class id]

foreach( $result as $row) {
    $thisRow = array();
    foreach ( $cols as $colName ) {
        $thisRow[] = $row['$colName']
    }
    $result['data'][] = $thisRow;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json', true, 200);
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

This should produce an object similar to:

```
{
    data: [
        ['Joseph Taylor', '22', '90']
    ],
    columns: [
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Position" },
        { title: "Score" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you... but the thing is... columns are dynamic.. some columns may present in one instance and may not present on other instance..

Comment: then either build the entire table into the JSON response with DataTables AJAX, or use the DataTables server-side approach (which ultimately is the same thing).